# Variable set to undefined from webViewDidStartLoad to webViewDidFinishLoad

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate, webviewdidfinishload

I have a `UIWebView` and the `UIWebViewDelegate`.

At the method `webViewDidStartLoad` I define a variable `bs` with another class `burningSoft`

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
    NSLog(@"burningSoft 1: %@", self.context[@"burningSoft"]);
    [self initJS];
    NSLog(@"burningSoft 2: %@", self.context[@"burningSoft"]);
    [self setContext:[[self webView] valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"]];
    if(self.context[@"burningSoft"].isUndefined) {
        self.context[@"burningSoft"] = [self bs];
    }
    NSLog(@"burningSoft 3: %@", self.context[@"burningSoft"]);
}
```

The method `initJS` looks like

```
-(void)initJS
{
    NSLog(@"initJS");
    [self setBs:[[BurningSoft alloc] init]];
    [[self bs] setMain:self];
    if(self.context[@"burningSoft"].isUndefined) {
        self.context[@"burningSoft"] = [self bs];
    }
}
```

and `webViewDidFinishLoad` looks similar like `webViewDidStartLoad`

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
    NSLog(@"burningSoft 4: %@", self.context[@"burningSoft"]);
    if(self.context[@"burningSoft"].isUndefined)
    {
        NSLog(@"UNDEFINED!!!");
        NSLog(@"[self bs] 1: %@", [self bs]);
        NSLog(@"burningSoft 5: %@", self.context[@"burningSoft"]);
        self.context[@"burningSoft"] = [self bs];
        NSLog(@"burningSoft 6: %@", self.context[@"burningSoft"]);
        NSLog(@"[self bs] 2: %@", [self bs]);
    }
    NSLog(@"burningSoft 7: %@", self.context[@"burningSoft"]);
}
```

So my first page did some logs like this

```
2016-08-26 13:42:57.054 burningSoft[2325:342056] webViewDidStartLoad
2016-08-26 13:42:57.055 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 1: (null)
2016-08-26 13:42:57.055 burningSoft[2325:342056] initJS
2016-08-26 13:42:57.056 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 2: (null)
2016-08-26 13:42:57.060 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 3: < burningSoft: 0x7fc7a3616870>
2016-08-26 13:42:57.300 burningSoft[2325:342056] webViewDidFinishLoad
2016-08-26 13:42:57.300 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 4: < burningSoft: 0x7fc7a3616870>
2016-08-26 13:42:57.300 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 7: < burningSoft: 0x7fc7a3616870>
```

and that's correct. If I entered some login data and another site is loaded I get logs like

```
2016-08-26 13:43:12.269 burningSoft[2325:342056] webViewDidStartLoad
2016-08-26 13:43:12.269 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 1: < burningSoft: 0x7fc7a3616870>
2016-08-26 13:43:12.270 burningSoft[2325:342056] initJS
2016-08-26 13:43:12.270 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 2: < burningSoft: 0x7fc7a3616870>
2016-08-26 13:43:12.270 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 3: < burningSoft: 0x7fc7a3616870>
2016-08-26 13:43:12.444 burningSoft[2325:342056] webViewDidFinishLoad
2016-08-26 13:43:12.445 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 4: undefined
2016-08-26 13:43:12.445 burningSoft[2325:342056] UNDEFINED!!!
2016-08-26 13:43:12.445 burningSoft[2325:342056] [self bs] 1: < burningSoft: 0x7fc7a5827230>
2016-08-26 13:43:12.445 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 5: undefined
2016-08-26 13:43:12.445 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 6: undefined
2016-08-26 13:43:12.445 burningSoft[2325:342056] [self bs] 2: < burningSoft: 0x7fc7a5827230>
2016-08-26 13:43:12.446 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 7: undefined
```

Everything is correct till the log `2016-08-26 13:43:12.445 burningSoft[2325:342056] burningSoft 5: undefined`. My variable `bs` has the correct content and I set this content in this method to `self.context[@"burningSoft"]` but the log in the next line told me that there is nothing.

Did someone know why my variable `self.context[@"burningSoft"]` set to undefined between the methods `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` and will not set?

Comment: Can you also log `self` and `self.context` to see whether the change is in those, as opposed to just the @"burningSoft" element?

Comment: @PhillipMills I solved it ... I only had to add `[self setContext:[[self webView] valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"]];` into `webViewDidFinishLoad`